# Как посмотреть результат препроцессора (подцветка Iintellisense) определенного файла, который является частью множества проектов

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

Суть такая: файл является частью множества проектов в солюшене. Соотвественно препроцессор будет давать разные результаты для файла. Можно ли указать проект, который будет использован при анализе intellisense? Set as startup не помогает в этом. Пробовал специально выбирать файл через explorer, но также не работает.

Comment: *"файл является частью множества проектов"* - ¿это как это так?

Comment: @user7860670, Так и читается. Например какой-нибудь `example.cpp` компилируется для `project1` и для `project2`, но у них разные директивы препроцессинга

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Выносите файл в (один) отдельный проект, а разные настройки препроцессора для него разносите по разным конфигурациям. Тогда intellisense будет показывать результаты для текущей конфигурации.

Comment: Получается, что другого варианта нет? Очень геморойно делать для множества разных файлов каждый раз. Но спасибо за вариант

Comment: Да вроде не особо напряжно должно быть. Главное не поступать, как те товарищи, которые для каждого нового проекта каждый раз вручную заполняют диалог настроек проекта и потом ноют на форумах, что VS не удобная.